# How can I assert that a particular method was called using NUnit?

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit, moq

How can I test that a particular method was called with the right parameters as a result of a test? I am using [NUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit).

The method doesn't return anything. it just writes on a file. I am using a mock object for `System.IO.File`. So I want to test that the function was called or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

More context is needed. So I'll put one here adding Moq to the mix:

```
pubilc class Calc {
    public int DoubleIt(string a) {
        return ToInt(a)*2;
    }

    public virtual int ToInt(string s) {
        return int.Parse(s);
    }
}

// The test:
var mock = new Mock<Calc>();
string parameterPassed = null;
mock.Setup(c => x.ToInt(It.Is.Any<int>())).Returns(3).Callback(s => parameterPassed = s);

mock.Object.DoubleIt("3");
Assert.AreEqual("3", parameterPassed);
```

Comment: Does this work when Calc is not abstract or interface ? As far as I know `Moq` make dynamic proxies to make its mocks not generating new IL instructions in order this to be possible...

Answer (score 11):

You have to use some mocking framework, such as [Typemock](http://www.typemock.com) or [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx), or [NMocks2](http://www.nmock.org/cheatsheet.html).

NUnit also has a [Nunit.Mock](http://www.zorched.net/2007/03/10/mocking-net-objects-with-nunit/), but it is not well-known.

The syntax for moq can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/moq/):

```
var mock = new Mock<ILoveThisFramework>();

// WOW! No record/reply weirdness?! :)
mock.Setup(framework => framework.DownloadExists("2.0.0.0"))
    .Returns(true)
    .AtMostOnce();

// Hand mock.Object as a collaborator and exercise it, 
// like calling methods on it...
ILoveThisFramework lovable = mock.Object;
bool download = lovable.DownloadExists("2.0.0.0");

// Verify that the given method was indeed called with the expected value
mock.Verify(framework => framework.DownloadExists("2.0.0.0"));
```

Also, note that you can only mock *interface*, so if your object from `System.IO.File` doesn't have an interface, then probably you can't do. You have to wrap your call to `System.IO.File` inside your own custom class for the job.

Comment: NUnit just runs tests, it doesn't do mocking or verification.  Different responsibilities.  You should be able to verify the expectations on your mock object, though I haven't used Moq.

Comment: yep i was looking at the wrong place... I was looking in nunit. now i am looking at moq. :)

Comment: MOQ will allow you to mock abstract classes too.

Answer (score 3):

By using a mock for an interface.

Say you have your class `ImplClass` which uses the interface `Finder` and you want to make sure the `Search` function gets called with the argument "hello";

so we have:

```
public interface Finder 
{
  public string Search(string arg);
}
```

and

```
public class ImplClass
{
  public ImplClass(Finder finder)
  {
    ...
  }
  public void doStuff();
}
```

Then you can write a mock for your test code

```
private class FinderMock : Finder
{
  public int numTimesCalled = 0;
  string expected;
  public FinderMock(string expected)
  {
    this.expected = expected;
  }
  public string Search(string arg)
  {
    numTimesCalled++;
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, arg);
  }
}
```

then the test code:

```
FinderMock mock = new FinderMock("hello");
ImplClass impl = new ImplClass(mock);
impl.doStuff();
Assert.AreEqual(1, mock.numTimesCalled);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Rhino Mocks where is a method called AssertWasCalled

Here is a way to use it

```js
var mailDeliveryManager = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMailDeliveryManager>();

var mailHandler = new PlannedSending.Business.Handlers.MailHandler(mailDeliveryManager);

mailHandler.NotifyPrinting(User, Info);

mailDeliveryManager.AssertWasCalled(x => x.SendMailMessage(null, null, null), o => o.IgnoreArguments());
```